# hide some class file or package in jar file

Tags: java, jar

How can I export a jar without some class or package which I don't want others to use,but which is needed in project,means I can't delete them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This doesn't make a lot of sense.

If the classes are needed to compile the project, then there are likely to be static dependencies on them in other classes.  (Otherwise ... you would be able to just delete it / them.)

But if there are static dependencies on those classes, then you won't be able to run the applications unless those classes are present in the JAR file.  If you leave the classes out of the JAR to stop people using them (or whatever), your application will die on startup with "class not found" exceptions.

If you want to stop people using the classes directly, you could try the following:

- Change the classes access to "package private".  This doesn't make it impossible to use them, but it makes it more difficult.
- Change your project so that the dependencies on the classes are entirely dynamic; e.g. via `Class.forName(...)` or dependency injection.  Then you can exclude the classes from the JAR as required.  But once again, if your application needs to use the classes, they have to be accessible at runtime (somehow), and it will therefore be possible (somehow) for other people to get hold of them.
- Change your project to allow you remove the classes entirely.  This is the only sure-fire solution.

Finally, before you go to all of this trouble you should ask yourself why you are even bothering to do this.  Why don't you just let people use the classes anyway?  What is to stop them getting the classes from somewhere else ... or implementing their own versions from scratch?

Comment: +1 for package-private. If you want to hide classes from the outside world (at least as far as class resolution goes), this is the way to go. Since there are no "friend" packages in Java (it is only package-private or whole-world-public) this restricts your ability to split your own code into multiple packages, though.

Comment: 'Why don't you just let people use the classes anyway?' - When you create an API you don't want people to rely on implementation details because you will break their code when the internals change. As a designer of an API you are responsible for intuitive usage. So of course a user could use reflection to access a package private class, but this is cheating and they should not be surprised when their code will break some day. When no framework like OSGi or Netbeans RCP can be used, the way to go is package privacy.

Comment: @Alexander - Well, yea - but the point is that it is not your responsibility to protect people who wilfully break the rules.  And that includes the rule that you should not depend on the internals of someone else's code.  If people do that and something goes wrong, then they are to blame, not you.

Answer (score 2):

If the class is needed for your program to work, you can't omit it from the JAR.

You can put classes in a package that has something like "internal" in its name — e.g. `com.example.internal` — to indicate that the classes aren't meant for others to use or rely on.  It can't *prevent* anyone from using your class for their own purposes, but it at least indicates that they do so at their own risk, that your internal interfaces might change in future versions of the program, etc.

Answer (score 1):

A simple way is to use the package private access modifier for classes. That will make it difficult for others to access the classes, but it will also affect your ability to use them from other packages.

A more advanced way would be to use OSGi and only publish those classes you want others to use. That will make it impossible for others to access the classes while not restricting your access to them.

Answer (score 0):

Put them into a separate jar file, include that jar file (as a single file, maybe with a nondescript name) into your jar file, create a custom class loader to open that embedded jar file from your code, bootstrap an entry point with reflection (because you cannot have static dependencies on it) into that new class loader .

Or just accept the fact that since the code is in there somewhere, any amount of obfuscation is just an inconvenience to everyone and cannot really hide anything.