# Excluding packages from external use in java

Tags: java, package

I am already writing a java library, and I want to not share some packages with program that uses my library.

When I finish I want to export my library to jar

Is that possible?

Comment: Are you talking about encapsulation or are you trying to hide your library internals?

Comment: @konsolas sorry, I am new java programmer and I did't unsterstood. Can you explain what is it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [hide some class file or package in jar file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4342453/hide-some-class-file-or-package-in-jar-file)

Comment: And sorry if my english is bad

Comment: @JuanCarlosMendoza I used package-private. Thank you for the link